# Is there a good way to bypass restrictions on running EXE files?

Tags: windows, restriction

I have to compute at libraries quite often these days, and have been having some issues with my U3 smart drive. Despite working on some computers, public libraries here restrict the execution of EXE files and disable AutoPlay, rendering my U3 apps useless. Is there a good way of getting around the restriction and getting something - anything - to run?

Comment: A question like this might get a better response on a cracker site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you succeed in bypassing the restrictions and get caught, you may be banned entirely from using the computers at the library.  I recommend living without the executables or finding a computer to use somewhere else.

Comment: Somehow I figured that would be the answer... :D Should I open another question for, say, why it worked before and is now broken?

Comment: My guess is that the sysadmin deployed a new Group Policy Object to the domain to forbid it.  The only way to know for sure is to ask the techies at the library, but that will put you on their radar, which you may or may not want.

Comment: Yeah, the error mentions "Security Policy". Eh, it's not super-critical; I still have Firefox, and this is one of my rarer haunts.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the restrictions are in place to prevent precisely that.  Perhaps the restrictions are operating as intended.

Comment: I have gotten U3 to run on these computers before, so it's rather odd that it's not working this time around.